# Why does the delta-time of the python loop increase when a websocket connection is active?

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, python-asyncio

I have a python app that needs to maintain a connection with a client but also needs to run a loop. I do this with asyncio and a framework called quart. But when I connect to the app, the delta time of the loop steadily increases over time. I do not know what is causing this.

This only happens when there is a client currently connected, otherwise the delta is steady.

```
@app.websocket('/ws')
async def handle():
    global running

    while True:

        if(running == 0):

            asyncio.ensure_future(mainloop())


        rData = json.loads(await websocket.receive())


before = int(time.time() * 1000)
async def mainloop():


    running = 1 

    while True:

        start = time.time()

        now = int(time.time() * 1000)
        delta = now - before
        delta = delta * 0.001
        before = now

        await asyncio.sleep(max(1./20 - (time.time() - start), 0))

        for IDs in clientIds:
            PlayerJsonData = json.dumps(IDs.data) 
            if(IDs.ws in connected):
                await IDs.ws.send(PlayerJsonData)
            else:
                clientIds.remove(IDs)  


app.run(host='localhost', port=os.environ.get('PORT', '80'))
```

How can I make it so the delta is constant even when a client is currently connected?

Comment: With a delta approach, it is expected the delta increase or decrease according to the time taken for each iteration. An alternative is ‘frame locking’ (with delta skips) which maintains a fixed time of each frame processed. In such a case, each frame would do a constant amount of work, such as 1/60 for 60fps.

Comment: Shouldn't the pause be `max(1./20 - delta, 0)` instead of `max(1./20 - (time.time() - start), 0)`? The latter always sleeps for 1/20th of a second (minus only by the miniscule duration between the two practically consecutive calls to `time.time()`).

Comment: Also, multiplying time by 1000 only to immediately divide it makes the code more complex for no apparent purpose.